# Residue field of an infinite extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory, local-field

Let $\zeta_1 \in \overline{\mathbb{Q}_p}$ such that $\zeta_1^p=p$, now let $\zeta_2 \in \overline{\mathbb{Q}_p}$ such that $\zeta_2^p=\zeta_1$ and so on with $\zeta_i^p = \zeta_{i-1}$.
I have to show that the resiude field of $K=\mathbb{Q} [ \zeta_1 , \zeta_2 , \dots ]$ is $\mathbb{F}_p$.
I noticed that $K = \bigcup_{i} \mathbb{Q}[\zeta_i]$ and I think that for every finite subfield $F$ of $K$ I can say that $F/\mathbb{Q}_p$ is totally ramified and so I can say that $K/\mathbb{Q}_p$ is totally ramified but I don't know if this is enough to show that the residue field of $K$ is $\mathbb{F}_p$, if not how can I prove that?

Comment: $\zeta_n$ is reserved for roots of unity. Use the notation $p^{1/p^k}$ and $K=\bigcup_k \Bbb{Q}_p(p^{1/p^k})$ (with this notation it is implicit but you can still mention it : that we mean a compatible sequence of $p^k$-th roots, ie. $(p^{1/p^k})^p=p^{1/p^{k-1}}$). By definition if $a\in K$ then $a\in \Bbb{Q}_p(p^{1/p^k})$ for some $k$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose the residue field is strictly larger than $\mathbb{F}_p$. Suppose the image of $\alpha \in \mathcal{O}_K$ is not in $\mathbb{F}_p$.

Now $\alpha$ lives in some finite extension $\mathbb{Q}_p(\zeta_i)$. But you agreed that the residue field doesn't extend for any finite extensions; contradiction.

Comment: I don't know why but I wasn't able to see it. Thanks